# Ruby gem error while trying to login to openshift via terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, git, openshift

I tried installing ruby and rails which did work. But now that I am trying to get openshift to work. In openshift, I have created the application and Now I just want to transfer all the files the git hub. So according to my understanding, I have to login into openshift then I can use git commands to transfer the updated files onto the server.

I run into following error message[The operating system I am using is Mac OS X] :

```
Spartons:JavaTutorials ripudamanflora$ rhc apps
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rhc' (>= 0) among 60 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rhc:22:in `<main>'
```

I can't even login into my openshift application via terminal:

```
Spartons:peel ripudamanflora$  rhc setup -l eripflo@gmail.com
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rhc' (>= 0) among 60 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rhc:22:in `<main>'
```

All I am trying to do is login to my application and update it. Please let me know if anything is not clear or more information is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First verify `ruby` is correctly installed:

```sh
$ ruby -e 'puts "Testing Ruby"'
```

From the error, it seems like you haven't installed the `rhc` gem. First check if it's installed:

```sh
$ which rhc
```

If `rhc` isn't installed, try this:

```sh
$ sudo gem install rhc
$ rhc setup
```

And try again. (If you're using Ruby Version Manager `rvm`, [use this](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-client-tools.html#ruby-version-manager)).

---

**Source:** [Installing the OpenShift Client Tools - MacOS X](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-client-tools.html#mac-os-x)